# Cisco Prefix List Won't Appear in Route Table

Tags: cisco, routing, cisco-ios, bgp, route-filter

I have the following prefix-list configured on our router:

```
ip prefix-list adsvr seq 5 permit 172.30.5.241/32
ip prefix-list adsvr seq 10 permit 134.239.130.143/32
ip prefix-list adsvr seq 15 permit 192.168.151.135/32
ip prefix-list adsvr seq 20 permit 192.168.181.182/32

ip prefix-list networks permit 10.15.0.0/16
ip prefix-list networks permit 10.18.3.0/24
ip prefix-list networks permit 10.18.10.0/24
ip prefix-list networks permit 10.18.48.0/20
ip prefix-list networks permit 10.16.7.0/24
ip prefix-list networks permit 10.16.77.0/24
ip prefix-list networks permit 10.19.0.0/22
ip prefix-list networks permit 10.16.3.0/24
ip prefix-list networks permit 10.16.8.128/25
ip prefix-list networks permit 10.16.1.0/24
```

I have configured a route-map as follows:

```
route-map allowed_Alfa_networks permit 10
match ip address prefix-list adsvr networks
```

I have applied the route-map to our bgp configuration as follows:

```
router bgp 65230
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 10.9.252.90 mask 255.255.255.255
 network 10.16.76.0 mask 255.255.255.0
 network 10.112.224.0 mask 255.255.254.0
 network 10.112.226.0 mask 255.255.254.0
 network 10.112.228.0 mask 255.255.254.0
 network 10.112.230.0 mask 255.255.254.0
 network 10.112.232.0 mask 255.255.255.0
 network 10.112.233.0 mask 255.255.255.0
 network 192.168.58.0
 redistribute static
 neighbor 10.1.243.17 remote-as 2856
 neighbor 10.1.243.17 ebgp-multihop 3
 neighbor 10.1.243.17 soft-reconfiguration inbound
 neighbor 10.1.242.17 route-map allowed_Alfa_networks in
```

However, when I do a show ip bgp I only see the prefixes from 'networks' - I don't see prefixes from 'adsvr', see below;

```
     Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
 *>  10.0.0.0         0.0.0.0                  0         32768 ?
 *>  10.9.252.90/32   0.0.0.0                  0         32768 i
 *>  10.16.1.0/24     10.1.243.17                            0 2856 65201 i
 *>  10.16.3.0/24     10.1.243.17                            0 2856 64521 ?
 *>  10.16.7.0/24     10.1.243.17                            0 2856 64521 ?
 *>  10.16.45.0/25    10.1.243.17                            0 2856 65248 i
 *>  10.16.45.128/25  10.1.243.17                            0 2856 65248 i
 *>  10.16.76.0/24    0.0.0.0                  0         32768 i
 *>  10.16.77.0/24    10.1.243.17                            0 2856 64521 ?
 *>  10.19.0.0/22     10.1.243.17                            0 2856 65286 ?
 *>  10.19.8.0/22     10.1.243.17                            0 2856 12641 65289 ?
 *>  10.19.9.0/27     10.1.243.17                            0 2856 12641 65289 i
 *>  10.112.224.0/23  0.0.0.0                  0         32768 i
 *>  10.112.226.0/23  0.0.0.0                  0         32768 i
 *>  10.112.228.0/23  0.0.0.0                  0         32768 i
 *>  10.112.230.0/23  0.0.0.0                  0         32768 i
 *>  10.112.232.0/24  0.0.0.0                  0         32768 i
 *>  10.112.233.0/24  0.0.0.0                  0         32768 i
 *>  134.239.128.0/21 0.0.0.0                  0         32768 ?
 *>  141.247.238.0/24 0.0.0.0                  0         32768 ?
 *>  172.16.0.0/12    0.0.0.0                  0         32768 ?
 *>  172.23.204.0/22  10.1.243.17                            0 2856 65287 ?
 *>  172.50.0.0       0.0.0.0                  0         32768 ?
 *>  192.168.0.0/16   0.0.0.0                  0         32768 ?
 *>  192.168.58.0     0.0.0.0                  0         32768 i
jmeu-heysham01-mpls#
```

Can some please tell me why I can't see

```
172.30.5.241/32
134.239.130.143/32
192.168.151.135/32
192.168.181.182/32
```

Its driving me crazy

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the neighbor, `10.1.242.17`, is advertising those routes to you?

Comment: What is received from the neighbor? show ip bgp 10.1.243.17 received-routes

Comment: Here is one of the routes from show ip bgp neighour advertised to me.                           *>  192.168.151.0    10.1.243.17                            0 2856 12641 65219 i As you can see its being advertised to me.

Comment: And again jmeu-heysham01-mpls#show ip bgp neighbors 10.1.243.17 received-routes | inc 192.168.151.
 *>  192.168.151.0    10.1.243.17                            0 2856 12641 65219 i

Comment: No, `192.168.151.0` is not one of the routes you say is not being advertised, nor is it in the prefix list.

Comment: Its just won't advertise / filter on individual hosts.. but I don't understand why. However, it will filter on networks.

Comment: Are the individual hosts being advertised from somewhere. You can only filer routes which are being advertised. If the route `192.168.151.0` is being advertised, but the host route `192.168.151.35` is not being advertised, you will never see the host route.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you don't want to get the full route prefix, only the host route prefix, which you want to create out of the full route prefix.

I think you are confused. BGP will only get prefixes which are advertised to it. It appears that you are getting the the `192.168.151.0/24` prefix, but you wan to extract individual host prefixes from it, like `192.168.151.135.32`. That's not how it works.

You can filter any prefixes which you receive, but your are not receiving any host prefixes, so you can't filter on them. You neighbor would need to send you the host prefixes before you can filter on them.

If your neighbor is sending you both `192.168.151.0/24` and `192.168.151.135/32`, you can filter out one or the other, but if you only receive one of the prefixes, you can't create the other from the one you receive (except for aggregates).

Comment: Great thanks. I think this has completely answered my question.